# Should language tags exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

For tagging, would it be useful to have language tags?

My perspective would be that we should have an [introductoryprogramming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductoryprogramming) tag (which we do) and also have general field tags where it's beneficial, for example I created a [web-development](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) tag. Should that be broken into front and back end? Should we introduce tags for compiled vs. interpreted? What would be a good way to organize languages by how they can be used as teaching tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suitable age range tags](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/suitable-age-range-tags)

Answer (score 5):

I'd be inclined to start with "coarse-grained" tags like [web-development](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development). I think if we generally get those tags right the needed "fine-grained" tags will emerge.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Most questions and answers relative to this site are language agnostic. Contrarily, if the language in use is important enough to the question, it should be _in_ the question. If the question is relative the language, it should probably be on SO, not here. The "coarse-grained" tags, however, can be helpful, since dealing with web development can be markedly different from database design and network setup.

Answer (score 3):

I think that we may need them in specific instances.  I'm a little worried that they will fracture the searchspace, but if we heavily encourage the use of other additional tags (such as your introductoryprogramming), I don't believe that they will be a significant drag.