# Broad tags make it difficult to write a good wiki

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 3 pages of tags. Some of them have a wiki, some don't. However, some are (as I find it) difficult to describe well in a tag wiki.

Examples are [security](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) (It is not so clear what kind of security it is about) or [ide](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) (what aspect of an ide is asked about). How could we deal with these tags? They should eventually, like all tags, have a wiki (If they remain). But if the intention of the one who created the tag is unclear (i.e. it is unclear in which sense the tag was created) it is difficult to make a good wiki. This is somewhat easier for [language tags](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-language-tags-exist) but not so much for other broad tags.

What do you think about tags like that?

Comment: I suspect that fairly soon we'll have to do a sweep of the tags looking for some of the deadwood to burn.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver as soon as tag synonyms become a thing (someone with enough rep to do them)

Answer (score 2):

For the one [security](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) question, I would re-tag as [security-awareness](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-awareness) which would cover some online security aspects. I imagine we might also get [security-implementation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-implementation) (i.e. don't brew your own, take a proven solution to a particular problem), or [security-protocols](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-protocols) for something digging into the how and why of TLS.

Answer (score 1):

So far, as far as I can tell, IDE has referred to ide choice (and really could be named ide-choice to mimic language-choice).

Comment: Oh. That does make sense... Now that I look at the question again.