# Can a hyphen be placed in the [introductoryprogramming] tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [introductoryprogramming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductoryprogramming) tag doesn't have a hyphen in the middle, as in: [introductory-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductory-programming). Since introductoryprogramming is only 23 characters, introductory-programming has 24 characters and should hence be allowed as a tag name (the maximal length is 25 characters).

Can a hyphen be placed in the [introductoryprogramming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductoryprogramming) tag? I could do it with manual retagging, but the tag has already 7 questions, so that doesn't seem the best thing to do right now.

Comment: I think retagging is the only way at this point. There isn't an automated system for this that I know of.

Comment: @thesecretmaster A diamond moderator (and hence a CM) can do it automatically.

Comment: Note: this is completed now.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, but maybe it should be [introductory-course](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductory-course) to match with the idea which was voted up on [the question about age range tags](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/58).

Comment: Yes. This makes it useful for non-programming courses as well.

Comment: This would have a different meaning. It may be a separately useful tag.