# Can we replace the "elderly" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It feels like [adult-education](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adult-education) might be a better fit for our site, unless we expect that retirement facilities will be a focus here.

The question, for reference:
[Programming curriculum for senior students (over 50 years)](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/203/programming-curriculum-for-senior-students-over-50-years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that elderly is still appropriate because in the question where it is used, the people in question are elderly in that the microsoft suite is alien to them. Adult implies some level of comoetence and computer knowledge that these people do not possess.

Comment: Fair enough :)  I'll go with that.

Answer (score 3):

I created the elderly tag, 'cause It was the best I thought  at that time, but I agree that is not a perfect tag. The "mature-learner" suggested [here](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/116) is also a good option to me.

Comment: I did it as per your suggestion. I figured, since you are OP and the owner of the tag, no further consensus was needed. :)

Comment: "mature learner" is far better since there are plenty of people over 50 who do not see themselves as "senior". Hence, "mature learner" is less offensive and more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

I think [higher-education](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-education) sounds even better...

Comment: "higher-education" typically applies to university level activities. In the context of the original question on the main site, that's definitely _not_ the target.