# How to make this tool more useful for elementary school computer science teachers

Tags: discussion, tags

A personal learning network (PLN) such as this board, is a great resource for computer science teachers who may be fairly isolated in their individual school. Here there are great resources for middle school and high school teachers of computer science.  With the movement to provide computer science for all K-12, the elementary school teacher of computer science needs support too. This board would be more useful if there was the ability to tag questions as k-5 and/or k-8.  As a new user, I don't have the ability to add new tags.  This discourages asking questions that don't fit with the existing tag topology because the focus to date has been in the secondary arena.

Comment: Note that I added K-5 as a tag and can add others. But come to the classroom to discuss.

Comment: A lack of tags shouldn't discourage users. What we really need are some suitable 'recognisable' questions that come up in search, so a new user can either copy the existing tags, or feel encouraged to pick an arbitrary tag. Editing the tags on a question is easy for other users...

Answer (score 3):

This has come up before.  You may want to see the discussion [here](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/suitable-age-range-tags).  There were concerns with the grade numbers being US-centric, and we wound up with the tags [primary-school](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primary-school), [high-school](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school), and [undergraduate](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate).  (The [graduate](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate) tag referenced in the top post there was never used, though [adult-education](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adult-education) did eventually appear.)

[high-school](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) has been, by far, our most popular age-related tag, followed by [undergraduate](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate).  I think this stems largely from the demographics of our earliest adopters. But we're a welcoming bunch, and this is a great community.  We would ***love*** to have more [primary-school](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primary-school) discussions going on.

Comment: Actually, I added a [tag:k-5] tag and gave wiki explanation of it. I noted that it is a US term.

Answer (score 0):

One problem we have with tags is that there are a lot of them and for a new user it isn't obvious that there is one that applies. I didn't know about [primary-school](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primary-school) myself and wouldn't have been likely to find it in a search while writing a question.

Note that a search in tags seems to only search on the tag names, not their text. So, you basically have to look at them all or you have to know something about the name itself to find a given tag.

Comment: If the site needs [tag:k-5] this should probably be a synonym of [tag:primary-school] since the use will mostly overlap.

Comment: Some places primary means K-8 actually. We also have middle school, but not everywhere. So, not quite the same.

Comment: yes, but for the purpose of the tag, these precise details shouldn't matter. Arguably the tag is mostly redundant, and the question needs to cover the contest anyway. The before/in university boundary is clearer, but there will be a lot of overlap in what is taught for both sides.

Comment: I'm fine with all these responses.  I didn't see primary-school in the tags.  I am ok if that means K-8 because it still would limit the topics I would browse. I also like the idea of k-5 or k-8 being a synonym for primary, then the US people could search on k-5 and the international could search on primary-school.  All would find pertinent posts.

Comment: Yes, but you would find discussion in the classroom valuable. It is inhabited by people with a lot of knowledge about the site and about education. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/the-classroom